# JavaScript prevent window location from occurring if there is no query string

Tags: javascript

my JavaScript is not working properly...its suppose to do a window location if there is a query string and if there is not then no window location should trigger. The window location does happen if there is a query string or not. Basically I want to stop it from occurring if there is no query string on the URL. Here is the code:

```
            var url = $(location).attr("href");
            if (url.indexOf("?") > 0){
                url = url.substr(0,url.indexOf("?"));
            } else {
                return false;
            }
            window.location(url);
```

How can I stop my window location from happening when there is no query string?

Comment: Something like `if(location.search) location = location.hostname + location.pathname;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will send you to whatever your url is, after stripping off the search string. It will do nothing if there is no search string.

```
if (location.search) {
    location.search = '';
}
```

Comment: @Benjamin - thanks to your initial comments I did a little experimenting with the various parts of window.location